# Google Sheets to link to Google Team Calendar using Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-docs, google-apps-script-editor

Hi I've been trying to experiment with google's script editor and i think that I've gotten the code right but it wont seem to work. I used the code they made in google's tutorial video with edits but it cant seem to create an event. On the executions  page it says completed but no new event is showing up.

Anyway i've attached screen shots of the sheet as well as the code. Hope y'all can help thanks!

```js
function scheduleMeetings() {
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange('H6').getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var tasks = spreadsheet.getRange("G10:H100").getValue(); 
  
  
  for (x=0; x<tasks.length; x++) {
    var schedules = tasks[x];
    var date = schedules[0];
    var task = schedules[1]; 
    
    eventCal.createAllDayEvent(task, date);
     
  }
  
 }
```

[image: The screen capture of the spreadsheet]

[image: Code using Script Editor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function scheduleMeetings() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange('H6').getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var tasks = spreadsheet.getRange("G10:H100").getValues();//you had getValue() 
  for (var x=0;x<tasks.length;x++) {
    var schedules = tasks[x];//Select a row
    var date = schedules[0];//column G
    var task = schedules[1];//column H
    //you may need to add var date=new Date(schedules[0]);
    eventCal.createAllDayEvent(task, date); 
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked for me! I had to ass the var date = new Date(schedules[0]);